# iptable drop command for consecutive ip addresses?

Tags: iptables

If i wanted to block consecutive ip addresses from 000.00.000.26 through 000.00.000.37 i could issue this command 12 times blocking each ip individually:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 000.00.000.26 -j DROP
```

Is there a way to revise the syntax so that it will block all 12 addresses with one command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 000.00.000.26-000.00.000.37 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work.

`iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 000.000.0.26-000.000.0.37 -j DROP`